# How "return false" can optimize your scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

So i'm reading this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance--net-5551, #9, reproduced below, I don't totally understand, can someone explain to me (in a different way than how it's been explained below)?

9. Return False
   You may have noticed whenever your functions don't return false, you jump to the top of the page.When dealing with longer pages, this result can be quite annoying.

So, instead of

```
$('#item').click (function () {
  // stuff here
});
```

Write

```
$('#item').click (function () {
  // stuff here
  return false;
});
```

Comment: while i'm too dumb to understand what that sentence says i'm not too dumb to realize i can ask no dumb questions on here =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is mostly true if `#item` is an anchor element with an href, which most likely looks something like `<a href="#" id="item">`

`return false` in the event handler is equivalent to `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`, which prevents the default execution of the native action, in this case going to the `#` hypertext reference and also stops the event from bubbling up.

---

[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/) has a good explanation ( as compared to `event.preventDefault()` ):

> The difference is that return false; takes things a bit further in that it also prevents that event from propagating (or "bubbling up") the DOM. The you-may-not-know-this bit is that whenever an event happens on an element, that event is triggered on every single parent element as well. So let's say you have a box inside a box. Both boxes have click events on them. Click on the inner box, a click will trigger on the outer box too, unless you prevent propagation.

Comment: yes i know this to be true for links, can you think of other examples where you might want to do `event.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would assume you only want to stop the bubbling where there is a parent element that also has that event listener. Other examples, maybe a keypress event, but no I haven't come across any that I can recall.  The comment about it being a link was more about the page scrolling to the top on click, which is generally a result of following through on anchors (unless there is other custom code).

Answer (score 1):

`.click(...)` is an alias for `.on("click", ...)`.

As described in the jQuery documentation for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Returning `false` from an event handler will automatically call `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`. A `false` value can also be passed for the handler as a shorthand for `function(){ return false; }`. So, `$( "a.disabled" ).on( "click", false );` attaches an event handler to all links with class "disabled" that prevents them from being followed when they are clicked and also stops the event from bubbling.

This is a feature (one of many) jQuery adds for convenience.

As for performance, I'm not sure this increases it in any meaningful way.

---

That article in general is mainly "stuff I heard on the internet". I doubt the author truly understands the why's of the various tips they give.

For example, if you are caching selects (#6) then you're not going to get much out of preferring ids over classes for selections (#4).

Another example is #3 which is basically saying "don't use jQuery". Using anything in jQuery is going to cause a microscopic decrease in performance but that's the trade off you agree to when you decide to use jQuery at all. The point of jQuery isn't so much about improving performance, it's about improving convenience.

Comment: i'd definitely use this for links (see other answer), but aside from that, that's where I was wondering what else this is helpful for. Referencing that `return false` calls `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()` was what I was looking for in terms of an actual answer. Thanks!